# "Duplicate" option causes volume to be "-1"

Tags: c#, duplicates, libvlcsharp

Within our C# development, the below "duplicate" command is used in-order to allow one stream for viewing & the other for recording. However it triggers the volume to be set at "-1" automatically. Manually setting the volume higher through source-code, doesnt help either.

```
string[] mediaOptions = new string[] { ":avcodec-hw=d3d11", ":sout=#duplicate{dst=display,dst='transcode{vcodec=h264,vb=0,scale=0,acodec=mp4a,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:std{access=file,mux=mp4,dst=" + filename + "}'}" };
```